# how to access variables inside a url in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to access variables inside a url in react?

```
let pincode='560001';
axios.get('https://api2-4oagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?pinCode={this.pincode}')
```

Comment: you have to create one variable for whole url and use that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call your pincode using below code:

you have to remove this keyword from pincode..and also you have to use Template literals string as i have mentioned below use `` instead ''

```
let pincode='560001';
axios.get(`https://api2-4oagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?pinCode={pincode}`)
```

Comment: use const inside your function e.g function(){const pincode="560001"} and try

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let pincode='560001';

axios.get(`https://api2-4oagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?pinCode=${this.pincode}`)
```

and this is more like es6 string templete. please check following link

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: thanks gnujoow,tried using ${pincode} but its not posible

Comment: you should wrap your code with `` backtick not quote

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use this.pincode.

Use below Code.

```
let pincode='560001';

axios.get(`https://api2-4oagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?pinCode=${pincode}`);
```

OR

```
let pincode='560001';

axios.get('https://api2-4oagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?pinCode='+pincode);
```

You will get your desired result.

Comment: tried both the methods gives pincode declared but not read error